# Using csv file in npm version of d3 v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, d3.js, npm

I am working on a react project and using d3. I have used npm to install d3 module in my project. I am having version 5.9.2 of d3 currently in my project. I have a csv file which I want to use in the d3. I have tried searching a way to use it but couldn't get even one resource for the same. Every post is using the csv file like this:

```
d3.csv("sp500.csv", type, function(error, data) {
    if (error) throw error;

    //do something here
}
```

But I don't have any module named d3.csv in my installed modules. All I have is **d3-dsv**

Currently I am trying to use it in this way

```
import {dsvFormat, csvParse, csvParseRows, csvFormat, csvFormatBody, csvFormatRows} from 'd3-dsv'

csvFormat("sp500.csv", this.type.bind(this), function(error, data) {

            console.log("data is")

            //do something here
}
```

But I have no luck here. Seems like csvFormat is not the equivalent fuction of d3.csv. How can I use csv file?

Comment: It's not `import from 'd3-dsv'`, it should be `import from 'd3-fetch'`.

Comment: import {csv} from "d3-fetch" like this?

Answer (score 0):

Your d3.csv syntax is from old versions if D3. In latest versions D3 uses fetch for downloading resources and `d3.csv` (and other similar methods like `d3.json` and `d3.text`) syntax is changed to be similar to `fetch` syntax:

```js
let url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oncletom/coursera-ml/master/week-1/people-example.csv";

d3.csv(url).then(data => {
  console.log(data)
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```